# <ErrorMessage /> doesn't work despite function call

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik

I'm using Formik to build a simple form.

In my `validation` method I'm checking to see if a name has been entered into the field. If it has not, then I print into the console - which is working fine.

```
validate={values => {
  let errors = [];

  if (!values.name) {
    console.log("no name entered");
    errors.name = "First name required";
  }

  //check if my values have errors
  return errors;
}}
```

However, the `<ErrorMessage />` component does nothing when the above condition is met:

```
  <Field
    type="text"
    name="name"
    placeholder="First Name"
  />
  <ErrorMessage name="name" />
```

Why is this?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/94n93083vw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have `let errors = [];` instead of `let errors = {};`.